# Cakephp authentication plugin how can I add difference session key?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In present scenario after login in front end if I visit /admin prefix. It's accessing admin panel. Here I'm using difference model for login. For front end I'm using users table and for admin I'm using admin_users table. I have made this changes in application.php like

```
if($request->getParam('prefix') == 'Admin')
{
            $identifierSettings += [
                'resolver' => [
                    'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
                    'userModel' => 'AdminUsers',
                ],
            ];
}
```

How could I add difference session key for admin and front-end ?

Answer (score 0):

In Authentication.Session

Set your session key for admin `'sessionKey' => 'Auth.admin'`

Note : Default sessionKey is `Auth`

Details : https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authenticators.html#session